# NetSuite Advanced PDF - Unable to loop through JSON built from addCustomDataSource N/render function

Tags: netsuite, freemarker, suitescript2.0

Hope you can help.

I have a custom advanced PDF template on NetSuite, which needs to loop through a JSON object, constructed using the "addCustomDataSource" function from the N/render module. Right now, it only returns the FIRST line of the JSON, rather than printing every line.

Here is a snippet of what the JSON looks like after its compiled:

```
{
   lines: [
      {
         item: "BOM 89",
         custcol_itemdisplayname: "White Cabinet (made to order)",
         unit: "Ea",
         quantity: "1",
         amount: ".00"
      },
      {
         item: "ABC 20019 N",
         custcol_itemdisplayname: "231-670cm Natural",
         unit: "Ea",
         quantity: "1",
         amount: ".00"
      },
      {
         item: "ABC 10040 N",
         custcol_itemdisplayname: "203cm Natural",
         unit: "Ea",
         quantity: "1",
         amount: ".00"
      },
      {
         item: "ABC 10020 N",
         custcol_itemdisplayname: "115cm Natural",
         unit: "Ea",
         quantity: "1",
         amount: ".00"
      }
   ]
}
```

Here is a snippet of the loop I am using within the <#list> directive of the PDF template:

```
<#assign line_no = 0>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%;"><!-- start items -->
   <#list results.lines as result>
    <#if result_index==0>
      <tr>
        <td style="height: 29px; width: 120px;"><strong>Part Number</strong></td>
        <td style="height: 29px; width: 60px;"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td align="left" style="height: 29px; width: 200px; text-align: right;"><strong>Description</strong></td>
        <td align="center" style="height: 40px; width: 40px; text-align: center;"><strong>Cty of Mfg</strong></td>
        <td align="center" style="height: 29px; text-align: left; width: 60px;"><strong>UOM</strong></td>
        <td align="right" style="height: 29px; text-align: right;"><strong>Qty</strong></td>
        <td align="right" style="height: 29px; text-align: right;"><strong>Value</strong></td>
      </tr>
    </#if>
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 120px;">${result[line_no].item}</td>
        <td style="width: 60px;"><strong>&nbsp;</strong></td>
        <td align="left" style="width: 200px; text-align: right;">${result[line_no].custcol_itemdisplayname}</td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 40px; text-align: center;">UK</td>
        <td align="center" style="text-align: right; width: 60px;">Pieces</td>
        <td align="right" style="text-align: right;">${result[line_no].quantity}</td>
        <td align="right" style="text-align: right;">${result[line_no].amount}</td>
      </tr>
      <#assign line_no = line_no + 1> <-----THIS IS USED TO INCREMENT TO NEXT POSITION
  </#list>
</table>
```

Here is the SuiteScript snippet to create the data source as a JSON object:

```
       renderer.addCustomDataSource({
                format: render.DataSource.OBJECT,
                alias: "results",
                data: searchData
            });
```

I have used "results" as the variable in the <#list> directive as named in the SuiteScript function call above. Because the first line is returned, I am fairly positive the issue is not related to this.

As far as I see, everything is built correctly because I am also able to access specific positions of the construct within the PDF. For instance, the PDF outputs data for the following just fine:

```
${result[1].amount}
${result[2].amount}
${result[3].amount}
```

This leads me to believe the issue relates to the line_no variable in the PDF. That being said, this is the final output of the PDF itself:

[image]

Notice that the "line_no" variable prints each line successfully. So why would ${result[line_no].amount} NOT work?
Can anyone advise what could be stopping the template from iterating through the object?

Hope to hear back soon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `<#list results.lines as result>`, each `result` is a single line - you do not need to create your own index (`line_no`) to iterate.  Therefore `${result[line_no].amount}` should just be `${result.amount}`.  I'm more puzzled why it's working for the first line - but I expect it's because at that point `line_no` is undefined so Freemarker just ignores it.

Comment: Argh answer so simple, yet so effective. This was it. I knew I was missing something. Thanks again @krypton

Comment: `${result[1].amount}` aborts template processing with error in normal FreeMarker (unless it was deliberately configured to suppress errors and continue). But at Netsuite they took some now old version of FreeMarker, and modified it, so I'm not sure how that behaves.